# An argument or block definition is required here

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am using `kubernetes_network_policy` resource. I am trying loop over the ports and getting this issue.

```
╷
│ Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on main.tf line 16, in resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "example-policy":
│   16:     { for i in range(length(val.egress_number)):
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here.
```

**My Resource**

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "example-policy" {
  for_each = var.inputs
  metadata {
    name      = each.value.name
    namespace = each.value.namespace
  }
  spec {
    pod_selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = each.value.selector
      }
    }
    policy_types = each.value.policy

    egress {
    { for i in range(length(egress_number)):
      ports {
          port     = egress_number[i]
          protocol = egress_protocol[i]
      }
    }
      to {
        namespace_selector {
          match_labels = {
            app = each.value.egress_label
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My varibale.tf**

```
variable "inputs" {
  type = map(object({
    name            = string
    namespace       = string
    selector        = string
    policy          = list(string)
    egress_number   = list(string)
    egress_protocol = list(string)
    egress_label    = string
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

**My tfvars**

```
  inputs = {
    app = {
      name           = "nignx"
      namespace       = "default"
      selector        = "nignix-app"
      policy          = ["Egress"]
      egress_label    = "play"
      egress_number   = ["443", "8080"]
      egress_protocol = ["TCP", "TCP"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "example-policy" {
  for_each = var.inputs
  metadata {
    name      = each.value.name
    namespace = each.value.namespace
  }
  spec {
    pod_selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = each.value.selector
      }
    }
    policy_types = each.value.policy
    
    dynamic "egress" {
        
        for_each = range(length(each.value.egress_number))
        
        content {
            ports {
                port     = each.value.egress_number[egress.value]
                protocol = each.value.egress_protocol[egress.value]
            }
            
            to {
                namespace_selector {
                    match_labels = {
                        app = each.value.egress_label
                    }
                }
           } 
      }       
    }    
  }
}
```

Instead of using `range` and `length`, one could also use [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/zipmap) in your case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. now I understood the practical usage of dynamic blocks